# Laravel ENV variable collision in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: php, laravel, docker, redis, kubernetes

I came to a very specific case by using Laravel framework as a part of a kubernetes cluster. These are the facts, which have to be known:

- I've created a Docker container for caching called `redis`
- I've created a Docker container for application called `application`
- These two work together in a Kubernetes cluster

Kubernetes is setting ENV variables in each Docker container. Commonly, one is called `{container-name}_PORT`. Therefore, Kubernetes has created the ENV variable `REDIS_PORT` in my `application` container, which is set to something like that: `tcp://{redis-container-ip}:{redis-container-port}`.

Laravel sets this ENV variable too, but use it as a standalone port variable like `6379`. However, in this specific case, Redis does not work in Laravel, because of overwritten `REDIS_PORT` variable. The framework try to fetch redis on this example host string inside Kubernetes: `tcp://redis:tcp://10.7.240.204:6379`. Laravel logic behind: `{scheme}://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}`. You can see, `REDIS_PORT` is filled with `tcp://10.7.240.204:6379`.

**What is preferable to solve the issue?**

In my opinion, Kubernetes uses the ENV variable for `{container-name}_PORT` in a wrong way, but I do understand the internal logic behind Kubernetes ENV variables.

At the moment, I have changed my `config/database.php` configuration in Laravel, but this causes a review of changelogs on every update.

*Some of other details can be read here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24999*

Comment: what do you mean by a review of changelogs on every update?

Comment: Because of the overwritten out-of-the-box configuration of Laravel.

Comment: they are meant to be changed they are part of "your" application

Comment: I see you resolved your issue on github: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24999. Would be nice if you add an answer here describing your resolution.

Answer (score 1):

@Florian's [reply](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24999) to himself on github:

My solution was to change the config in `config/database.php` like that:

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'scheme' => 'tcp',
        'host' => env('REDIS_SERVICE_HOST', env('REDIS_HOST','127.0.0.1')),
        'port' => env('REDIS_SERVICE_PORT', env('REDIS_PORT',6379)),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

Now, the config checks first, if the REDIS_SERVICE_HOST and REDIS_SERVICE_PORT are present as ENV variable. This is the case, if you have a container in a docker/kubernetes cluster which is called REDIS.

Advantage of this solution is, that REDIS_SERVICE_HOST returns the IP address of the container, not a hostname. Therefore, there is no dns resolution anymore for this internal connections.